# Return of validate function not working with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to make a form, where users can change their email address of the account. I want them to enter their password to validate them. So I have a function that is doing the email change, but before it calls the `validate` function. If the return value is true it goes on. If not an error appears. But when testing it with the correct credentials it always goes into the `else` although i get a valid axios response.

```
    emailChange() {
      if (this.validate() == true) {
        var data = JSON.stringify({
          email: this.email,
        });
        this.put(data);
      } else {
        this.error = "Falsches Passwort";
        this.snackbar = true;
      }
    },

    validate() {
      var data = JSON.stringify({
        identifier: this.loggedInUser.email,
        password: "123456",
      });

      var config = {
        method: "post",
        url: "http://192.168.190.112:1337/api/auth/local",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: data,
      };

      this.$axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .then(function () {
          return true;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/328193)

Comment: Hm not really as I am using ```then``` in my function.

Comment: "Using `then`" is not a magic wand.  The `return` in your `then` callback is returning from *that* callback function, not from your `validate` function.  The `validate` function *itself* never returns anything.  You have an asynchronous operation.  Either make use of Promises (making `validate` also `async` and return the Axios `Promise`) or introduce a callback structure for your operation.  Refer to the proposed duplicate more carefully.

Comment: Ah got it now. Thanks for the quick help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function return is not returning to validate. Axios is asynchronous and you need either a promise or a callback.

```js
      this.$axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .then(function () {
          return true; // this does not return to validate(). it returns just here
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

This is a way to implement it.

```js
    emailChange() {
      this.validate((error, isValid) => {
        if (isValid) {
          var data = JSON.stringify({
            email: this.email,
          });
          this.put(data);
        } else {
          this.error = "Falsches Passwort";
          this.snackbar = true;
        }
      })
    },

    validate(callback) {
      var data = JSON.stringify({
        identifier: this.loggedInUser.email,
        password: "123456",
      });

      var config = {
        method: "post",
        url: "http://192.168.190.112:1337/api/auth/local",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: data,
      };

      this.$axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .then(function () {
          callback(null, true);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          callback(error);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `.then()`.

Creating a request isn't instant, and it's completion depends on the server you're requesting data from to send you back a response. Because of this, axios uses asynchronous code to give you a `Promise` that will resolve after the request is complete.

The callback within the `.then()` function is called whenever the request is resolved (which could take multiple seconds with a slow connection).

The callback that contains your return statement could be called multiple seconds after your validate function ends, which isn't what you want.

I'd suggest using `async`/`await` as an alternative.

Declaring a function as `async` makes it return a Promise no matter what, which is what you want, and `await` waits for a promise to resolve before continuing.

Here's a quick example

```
// This function returns a promise!
async validate() {
  // axios.get() returns a promise, so we use await to wait until it's resolved
  let response = await axios.get("url") 

  // return the data (this is not a promise)
  // since the method is async, this will be automatically converted into a promise
  // that will resolve when the method returns something
  return response;
}

// you can only use "await" in async functions
async emailChange() {
  // wait until this.validate() is finished before continuing
  if(await this.validate() == true) {
    // etc.
  }
}
```

async/await is generally the preferred way to do this because it's much cleaner than chaining callbacks together with .then()

Hopefully this helps